# Probability distribution derivation given histogram of outputs

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, polynomial, derived-distributions

I'm not too versed in statistics, but I am currently dealing with a problem that pertains to probability. If any assumptions are off on my part, please correct me. I have a 2D polynomial function of degree $n$, $z = p_n(x,y)$, if I randomly sample uniformly values of $x$ and $y$ in their domains $x\in [a,b]$ and $y\in [c,d]$ thus $X = \mathcal{U}([a,b])$ and $Y = \mathcal{U}([c,d])$, I'll get some random value $Z = p_n(X,Y)$. If I do this $N$ times, where $N$ is some very large number then the normalized histogram of values of $Z$ will start resembling some probability distribution function. Is there a way for me to derive the actual analytical form of this function given that I know what $p_n(x,y)$ is?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need the inverse function afaik(ie basically the roots). take a simple example of z=x^2+y^2, this already gets tricky if the circle is not fully contained inside your rectangle.